# One field search for multiple values

Tags: mysql, search

What is the best and optimised way to write a SQL query to search for a term with multiple columns in a table?

For example I have a table of products:

```
id | title   | color_id
-------------------
 1 | Dress   | 1 (red)
 2 | T-shirt | 3 (blue)
 3 | Pants   | 2 (green)
 4 | Socks   | 1 (red)
 5 | Dress   | 2 (green)
 6 | Shoes   | 2 (green)
 7 | Pants   | 3 (blue)
```

And a table of colors:

```
id | color
----------
 1 | Red
 2 | Green
 3 | Blue
```

And if a user enters in the term **Red dress**, as a result (s)he must see `Product` with id `1`, and if user enters simply **Red**, as a result (s)he must see `Products` with id `1` and `4`.

**Update:** There may be some inputs like `dress red` or `red blue` too.

Real version of tables are more complex, but I tried to explain in a simplest way.

Comment: Will `product.title` and `colors.color` never contain more than one word? If the input string is "red green dress pants", should it return both red dresses and green pants?

Comment: Must users always submit a color first?

Comment: No, there may be some inputs like `dress red` or `red blue` too.
@YaK for `red green dress pants` no, this is not necessary, just a combination of 2 words I think is enough

Comment: Can you split the user input such that you can understand if it is a clothType or a color?

Comment: Namely here lies the problem, so basically I cannot guess what the user wrote in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution that just "works" could be:

```
SELECT *
FROM products
JOIN colors ON colors.id = products.color_id
WHERE 
    ( title = "red" AND color = "dress" ) OR
    ( color = "red" AND title = "dress" )
```

This condition might perform better, if the optimiser is dumb enough not to notice it by itself:

```
WHERE 
    ( title = "red" OR title = "dress") AND
    ( color = "red" OR color = "dress")
```

If you add more properties to the problem (besides "title" and "color"), and if and if storage is not an issue, you may want to merge (and duplicate) all textual properties into a single `VARCHAR` column, and run a fulltext search on this column.

```
CREATE TABLE products_properties (
    product_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    properties VARCHAR (255),
    FOREIGN KEY fk_product (product_id) REFERENCES products(id),
    FULLTEXT ftx_properties (properties)
);
```

The search becomes very simple:

```
SELECT products.*, colors.*
FROM products
JOIN colors ON colors.id = products.color_id
JOIN products_properties AS pp ON pp.product_id = products.id
WHERE MATCH(properties) AGAINST ("+red +dress")
```

This obviously makes no sense in this particular example, but the more properties, the more it will speed up the query. This denormalisation also comes at the cost of an increased complexity to maintain the `products_properties` table.

Now the problem becomes really hairy if you

- have to deal with less normalised inputs such as "red blue"
- have words that belong to both categories (eg. if "red" was also a valid cloth title) and still want to discriminate them (eg. a query like "red blue" returns a cloth named "red" with color "blue")

But it looks like this is outside of the scope of your question.

Answer (score 1):

If I were doing this in SQL, I would typically break down the query into individual words before doing the query, then build the query dynamically based on how many words there were.

So for your example, the query might end up looking like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products p
JOIN colors c ON c.id = p.color_id
WHERE 
p.title LIKE '%red%' OR
c.color LIKE '%red%' OR
p.title LIKE '%dress%' OR
c.color LIKE '%dress%'
```

If you have lots of tables though, this can start to get pretty complicated.  It's also not very efficient as its unlikely any indexes will be usable.

A better solution would be to use a dedicated text indexing product like Lucene (but that's a whole nother question..)

Comment: This solution will not give the right result, for example if I'll input **Red Dress** as a result will be all the products that have the color *Red*, and all products that have title *Dress* even those who have other color.

Answer (score 1):

My idea is to use a query like this:

```
set @search = 'red dress';

SELECT *
FROM
  products INNER JOIN colors
  ON products.color_id = colors.id
WHERE
  (FIND_IN_SET(title, REPLACE(@search, ' ', ','))>0)+
  (FIND_IN_SET(color, REPLACE(@search, ' ', ','))>0) =
  LENGTH(@search)-LENGTH(REPLACE(@search, ' ', ''))+1;
```

The two replaces inside FIND_IN_SET are used to make a list of properties separated by commas:

```
red,dress
```

I'm then checking if `title` is in this set. If it is present, the value of:

```
(FIND_IN_SET(title, REPLACE(@search, ' ', ','))>0)
```

will be evaluated to 1, 0 otherwise. The same is for `color`.

The number of the properties in the search string can be calculated as:

```
LENGTH(@search)-LENGTH(REPLACE(@search, ' ', ''))+1
```

(yes, it is a dirty trick!). If the number of the properties that matches is the same as the properties in the @search string, the row will be returned. Please notice that performances will be poor.

Fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19dbd/1).

Comment: Your solution works nice, but performance is an important requirement, anyway thanks for your time, I appreciate this